# Array groupby and count

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get day wise count from below data 
example:

`{ 'Tue Oct 01 2019': 3, 'Tue Oct 02 2019': 1 }`

But I'm not getting the expected result from the below code.

```js
const data = [ { Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' },{ Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' },{ Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' }, { Date: 'Tue Oct 02 2019' } ];

const result = data.reduce((total, value) => {
  total[value] = (total[value] || 0) + 1;
  return total;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you want is to group and get count:

```
const data = [ 
    { Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' },
    { Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' },
    { Date: 'Tue Oct 01 2019' }, 
    { Date: 'Tue Oct 02 2019' } 
];

const result = data.reduce((total, {Date}) => {
    total[Date] = (total[Date] || 0) + 1;
    return total;
  }, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` is an Object, use `value.Date` instead of just `value` :

```js
const data = [
  { Date: "Tue Oct 01 2019" },
  { Date: "Tue Oct 01 2019" },
  { Date: "Tue Oct 01 2019" },
  { Date: "Tue Oct 02 2019" }
];

const result = data.reduce((total, value) => {
  total[value.Date] = (total[value.Date] || 0) + 1;
  return total;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```